# Unit Testing a method containing Environment.Exit() call within it

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit

I have a public method say,

```
public void ErrorEncounter()
{
//Global Error Counter
gblErrorCount++;

//Process tremination
Environment.Exit();
}
```

This method terminates whenever it is called. However, it will update the **Global Error Count** which i'm suppose to test. Is there any way to perform Unit Testing on this method?

I'm Using **NUnit** Framework for Unit Testing.

Comment: There are several similar questions in SO, eg [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37340870/test-environment-exit-in-c-sharp). Injecting the exit method as an interface or function argument is perhaps the most testable option. Extracting the call to a separate mockable method is also a good option

Comment: On the other hand, how is `ErrorEncounter()` called? What code uses `gblErrorCount++` if `ErrorEncounter()` terminates the application? If this code is called by an unhandled exception handler to terminate the application after N errors, counting and terminating should be different methods called by that handler

Comment: We might want to log the Error count or any Error Description before terminating the process. Above mentioned code is one such scenario where a method is updating some Global parameter and terminating the process.

Comment: That's one *more* reason to split the method into a logging part and a terminating part. The link I posted shows how `Environment.Exit()` can be injected as an interface or mocked. Another option would be to inject it as an `Action` parameter ot `ErrorEncounter` whose default implementation would call `Environment.Exit()`. With all three options you can provide a special test version of the method and avoid terminating the application

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This method is designed to be difficult to test!

Most obviously, because it terminates the application when called. But also because it changes a global (I assume static) variable. Both of these things prevent writing a good unit test that calls the method.

Three ways around this:
1. Eliminate the method
2. Don't test the method
3. Modify the method

Option 1. If this method only called exit, then you could simply drop it and call Exit directly. However, that would make some other method difficult to test, so this isn't really a great option.

Option 2. Sometimes a method is so simple that you can avoid testing it. Whether this is such a method depends on how `gblErrorCount` is used elsewhere. It would appear, however, that incrementing the count has no effect, since the process immediately exits.

Option 3. Modify the method and those methods that call it. One approach would be to use an event handling mechanism and terminate the app in the event handler. You could make this easier to test by injecting a different event handler when running tests.

IOW, this is basically a pretty untestable method. Hopefully, you are in control of the system under test and can change it.

Comment: After reading your option 1 I though that maybe the method was introduced as a mockable wrapper for exit in the first place, namely to make unit-testing some other methods easier.  Such wrappers are then rather tested during integration testing.  Not that this would be a very cleanly written wrapper, given the name and the incrementing of the error count...

Answer (score 1):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37340870/test-environment-exit-in-c-sharp) contains answers that show how `Environment.Exit()` can be tested.
**Constructor Dependency Injection**

One option is to convert it into a dependency by injecting it through an interface :

```
interface ITerminator
{
    void Exit();
}

class RealTerminator
{
    void Exit()=>Environment.Exit();
}

public class MyErrorChecker
{
    ITerminator _terminator;
    public class MyErrorChecker(ITerminator terminator)
    {
        _terminator=terminator;
    }

    public void ErrorEncounter()
    {
        //Global Error Counter
        gblErrorCount++;

        //Process tremination
        _terminator.Exit();
    }
}
```

The test project will implement a fake terminator class that sets a flag if `Exit` is called:

```
class FakeTerminator:ITerminator
{
    public bool Called{get;private set;}
    public void Exit()
    {
        Called=true;
    }
}
```

**Mocking**

Another option is to mock it by extracting the call to a virtual method that can be replaced in a mock class :

```
public void ErrorEncounter()
{
    //Global Error Counter
    gblErrorCount++;

    //Process tremination
    ForceExit();
}

internal virtual void ForceExit()
{
    Environment.Exit();
}
```

The test project could create a mock error checker class:

```
class MockErrorChecker:MyErrorChecker
{
    public bool Called{get;private set;}
    public override void ForceExit()
    {
        Called=true;
    }
}
```

**Function injection**

This option isn't included in the linked question. Pass an `exit` `Action` as a parameter to `ErrorEncounter` whose default will be to call `Environment.Exit()` :

```
    public void ErrorEncounter(Action exitFn=null)
    {
        var doExit=exitFn ?? (()=>Environment.Exit());
        //Global Error Counter
        gblErrorCount++;

        //Process tremination
        doExit();
    }
```

The test could pass its own function that sets a flag:

```
[Test]
public void Test_Exit_Is_Called
{
    bool called;
    void fakeExit() { called=true; }

    thatClass.ErrorEncounter(fakeExit);

    Assert.True(called);
}
```